# iOS: Error deleting UItableviewCell :Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm implementing a UITableView. I'm also using CoreData. It works fine but when I try to delete a row I'm getting this error:

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]

Here is my implementation:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }

        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchRequest =
            NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Developers")
        do {
            let test = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            let objectToDelete = test[indexPath.row] 
            managedContext.delete(objectToDelete)
            do{
                try managedContext.save()
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

The issue is on this line `tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)`

But I haven't figure out why. Most of the samples I have found they are implementing the same 3 lines of code:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Any of you know what I'm doing or a work around this error?

Comment: Show the full error in your question. And add your `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You only need `deleteRows` so get rid off `beginUpdates` & `endUpdates`

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
```

2- You delete from Coredata while you should delete from the table's dataSource array

```
let test = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
let objectToDelete = test[indexPath.row] 
managedContext.delete(objectToDelete)
```

Like

```
arr.remove(at:indexPath.row)
```